# AWS CLI ec2 run-instances fails with --tag-specifications parsing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm referring to the following AWS documentation, attempting to use the CLI (from Windows) to launch an EC2 instance with tags specified at launch time:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#Using_Tags_CLI

I ran into some issues, so I decided to try the exact command as specified in the documentation:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]'
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tag-specifications': Expected: '=', 
received: ''' for
 input:
'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]'
^
```

So, how exactly do you specify the tags for run-instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much frustration and searching, I stumbled across a page that explained that [the syntax for run-instances is documented incorrectly](https://awsjp.com/AWS/Faq/c/Error-parsing-parameter-tag-specifications-D22E.html).  I understand just enough Japanese to see the "mistake" and "correct" labels on the examples and see that the single-quotes around the values for the tag-specifications cause it to fail.  The correct syntax is:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e --tag-specifications ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}] ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]
```